# Visual Studio Code error during SASS task runner setup

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I am new to web development in general, and I am trying to setup sass following the documentation here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css

However I am receiving this error:

> "An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory". On
>   the internet people are suggesting solutions, but they are related to
>   configuration of other editors.

My project looks like this, so you can have an idea how my project is set up:

[SASS project config screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1e0p.png)

I tried adding all design files in the same folder as the tasks.json file, but it didn't work and I got the same error.

**I have one more question: do I need to create the .css file, or does the task create it if it's not found?**

I appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 5):

I just figured this out, while looking for the same solution.

Your "args" have to be configured like this:

**`"args": ["./src/app/styles.scss", "./src/app/styles.css"]`**
or
`"args": ["./(static or assets folder)/(sass folder)/styles.scss", "./(static or assets folder)/(css folder)/styles.css"]`

The "./" points to the root of the project, then simply include the appropriate folder path.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The default setup for the Sass Task Runner on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css now looks like this:

```
// Sass configuration
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Sass Compile",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "node-sass styles.scss styles.css",
      "group": "build"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you get the error

> "An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory"

then change the configuration like:

`"command": "node-sass ./<your path>/styles.scss ./<your path>/styles.css",`